# Posso criar uma model responsável por mais de uma tabela no Laravel?

Tags: laravel, model

Gostaria de saber se posso criar uma model que retorne o resultado de mais de uma tabela no Laravel.

Comment: Não, em um model você vai tratar os dados de uma tabela, e também tratar os relacionamentos dessa tabela com outras como pode-se ver na [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships)

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente vale ressaltar que cada model é responsável por uma tabela no Laravel.

Exitem formas de você fazer isso porém com ferramentas diferentes, você pode ver [aqui neste link do próprio S.O(Em inglês)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22119118/multiple-tables-in-one-model-laravel), mais detalhes de como fazer isso.

Você pode criar uma tabela auxiliar e recuperar os dados com os [Relationships do laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships).

Enfim, há várias formas de você recuperar esta informação, basta dar uma olhada na documentação e ir testando pra ver qual fica melhor pra sua aplicação.

Answer (score 0):

Cada model, por via de regra, será uma tabela, recomendo usar relationship:

https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/resources/relationships.html#relationships